# How to import a NiFi_Flow.json or convert to a template?

Tags: apache-nifi

I've worked the whole day on a Nifi Flow in a local docker container. Once finished I've downloaded the flow as json file and killed the container. I now want it to import into my Nifi instance on Kubernetes. Unfortunately, it seems that the way to go is using templates. So I guess the download flow as JSON file function is a one way road? Or what is the purpose of this functionality?

Is there a ways to convert this JSON to a template.xml? Otherwise I have to redo all my work.

Comment: Give these a read:
1. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-import-a-flow-to-NiFi-registry-in-CDP-Cloud/ta-p/308335

2. https://www.datainmotion.dev/2020/03/using-nifi-cli-to-restore-nifi-flows.html

Comment: @Sdairs thanks a lot - in case you post as answer I'll accept and upvote..

Answer (score 5):

You can upload the flow definition when creating the Process Group. Use the "Browse" icon:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You need NiFi Registry to import:

Good resource: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-import-a-flow-to-NiFi-registry-in-CDP-Cloud/ta-p/308335

Personally, I do not like posts by Timothy Spann, it may be useful but lack "lots" of explanations.

Summary:

1. Install NiFi Registry
2. Connect NiFi with the registry
3. Import Json file manually or using NiFi Toolkit or NiPyAPI to do it programmatically.

Comment: True that, sometimes my articles are just notes for myself I should add more details.